# How to filter range of date from a particular column of a csv file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, cut

Consider the input file

```
1,10/22/2017,Scheduled
2,10/23/2017,Confimred
1,10/24/2017,NA
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,Scheduled
```

How do I filter date(within range) in 2<sup>nd</sup> column by providing date range as input?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `awk` and call shell `date` command [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe):

```
awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" -F, ' 
BEGIN{srt="date -d"start" +%s"; srt|getline start; close(srt);  
      ed="date -d"end" +%s"; ed|getline end; close(ed) } 
{ bkp=$0; epoch="date -d"$2" +%s";epoch |getline $2;close(epoch)}; 
    ($2>=start && $2<=end){print bkp}' infile
```

For the below input:

```
1,10/22/2017,Scheduled
1,10/24/2017,NA
1,10/24/2017,NA,NA
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,NA
5,9/30/2017,Confirmed
6,10/1/2017,Scheduled
```

With `start='10/24/2017'` and `end='11/1/2017'`, the result is:

```
1,10/24/2017,NA
1,10/24/2017,NA,NA
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67470/discussion-between-user8554534-and-s).

Comment: -1, this assumes Awk can compare dates reliably.  **Awk does not have any date-specific comparisons.**  This code will be extremely fragile and will break (for example) when the dates span multiple years.

Comment: awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" -F, '$2>=start && $2<=end' filename works fine by giving range of dates but if start="10/25/2017" and end="10/25/2017" and if the input file has only one entry with date 10/25/2017 then output is not obtained

Comment: @Wildcard Updated my answer, to does support date as date in awk calling shell date.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head data1

# start="10/29/2017" end="11/2/2017"
START="10/29/2017"
END="11/2/2017"

pl " Results, from $START through $END:"
dateutils.dgrep -i "%m/%d/%Y" ">=$START" '&&' "<=$END" < data1

pl " Unsorted file, data2:"
head data2

pl " Results, from $START through $END, randomly organized file:"
dateutils.dgrep -i "%m/%d/%Y" ">=$START" '&&' "<=$END" < data2
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file :
1,10/22/2017,Scheduled
2,10/23/2017,Confimred
1,10/24/2017,NA
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,Scheduled

-----
 Results, from 10/29/2017 through 11/2/2017:
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,Scheduled

-----
 Unsorted file, data2:
1,10/22/2017,Scheduled
1,10/24/2017,NA
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,Scheduled
2,10/23/2017,Confimred
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled

-----
 Results, from 10/29/2017 through 11/2/2017, randomly organized file:
1,10/29/2017,Scheduled
1,11/2/2017,Scheduled
3,11/1/2017,Scheduled
```

on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
```

Because the comparison is arithmetic on date-formatted data, the data can be in any order. The final result can be sorted if desired -- see sort, msort, dsort.
The dateutils codes are available in many repositories, and in OSX (via brew).

Some details for dateutils.dgrep:

```
dateutils.dgrep Grep standard input for lines that match EXPRESSION. (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/dateutils.dgrep
Package : dateutils
Home    : http://www.fresse.org/dateutils
Version : 0.3.1
Type    : ELF64-bitLSBsharedobject,x86-64,version1(S ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Home    : https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils (doc)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: Thanks to anonymous editor for catching my spelling errors. A downvote for each spelling error seems a touch harsh -- when I took English at William & Mary (In the Navy), that was the penalty for misspelling, but we were warned about it, and it WAS an English class. I have not seen any policies about that here. I looked on Meta for some guidance, and I didn't see a consensus for the issue of spelling, except when it was likely to cause confusion. I would have rather had a heads-up and tried to fix it myself. I usually do the spell check, and clearly omitted it here, perhaps on the final edit.